# HDMI connection does not support HDCP

Tags: hdmi, blu-ray, hdcp

My problem: error message when playing blu-ray movies stating that the HDCP encryption could not be established.

My setup:

1. A new projector (EPSON EMP TW700)
   with a HDCP-compliant HDMI port
2. a PC with a brand-new graphics adapter
   (Sapphire HD 4350 512MB DDR2)
   supporting HDCP
3. Connection made with a DVI cable (it's installed in my wall) and
   a DVI-HDMI adapter to connect the projector
4. Latest drivers and software

My questions:

1. What can I do to establish the HDCP connection?
2. Would it help to use the HDMI output of the graphics adapter instead of the DVI (could it be that the HDCP chip is only supported on HDMI?)
3. Any other ideas?

I am very thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your DVI to HDMI adapter.  You cannot have any adapters if you want to be HDCP compliant.  So to answer your questions:

1) What can I do to establish the HDCP connection?

**Get rid of the DVI to HDMI adapter.  Nothing between your GPU and display except an HDMI cable.**

2) Would it help to use the HDMI output of the graphics adapter instead of the DVI > (could it be that the HDCP chip is only supported on HDMI???)

**Yes it would help.**

3) Any other ideas???

**Since you are new, make sure to select the answer that solves your problem.**

Answer (score 0):

HDCP /can/ be supported on DVI, but it may not be in this case.  It's also possible that it's the adapter causing the problem (if it's a passive dongle it probably won't work with HDCP).  Try direct HDMI to HDMI.